# Select many intervals from a single table based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

My intend is to select many intervals based on column value at the same time..Is it possible 
          [image]

This is my sample data, it consists of 1024 rows ,i want to select multiple intervals based on wavelength column ex:(341-348) (551-664) (998-1021) from a single table

Comment: Yes, it most probably is. For more information please add more details ;)

Comment: Sure it is possible if you show us what you need...

Comment: I want to select many intervals at the same time from a single table

Comment: `select * from table where wavelength between 341 and 348 or wavelength between 551 and 664 or wavelength between 998 and 1021`. See [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) for comparison operators in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BETWEEN` and `OR` to get records:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
   WHERE wavelenght BETWEEN 341 AND 348 
         OR wavelenght BETWEEN 551 AND 664  
         OR wavelenght BETWEEN 998 AND 1021
```

Answer (score 0):

To query not for a specific value, but for a range of values, SQL invented the `BETWEEN` operator for the `WHERE` clause (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp), e.g.

```
SELECT columns
FROM yourtable
WHERE wavelength BETWEEN lowerbound AND upperbound;
```